# Union two tables with categories in a query that retrieves categories and its parents

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have a PHP function that returns me an array with category information. It is supposed to be provided with a $categoryId, and then return that category and any category "above" it. This is working:

Table structure of `tbl_categories`:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_categories` (
  `categoryId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `categoryParentId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `categoryName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `categoryDescr` varchar(400) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
ALTER TABLE `tbl_categories` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`categoryId`);
ALTER TABLE `tbl_categories`
  MODIFY `categoryId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

Code of MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
      @r AS _id,
      (SELECT @r := categoryParentId FROM tbl_categories WHERE categoryId = _id) AS categoryParentId,
      @l := @l + 1 AS categoryDepth
    FROM
      (SELECT @r := '.$categoryId.', @l := 0) vars,
      tbl_categories h
WHERE @r <> 0) T1
JOIN tbl_categories T2 ON T1._id = T2.categoryId
ORDER BY T1.categoryDepth DESC
```

But now, instead of one table I have two:

1. tbl_categories
2. tbl_categories_custom

They are identical in structure. The `categoryId` in `tbl_categories_custom` starts from 1000 and will not "collide" with the ones in `tbl_categories`
Categories in `tbl_categories_custom` can have their `categoryParentId` set to a `categoryId` in `tbl_categories`.

Now, my question is, how can I change my query above that works with just `tbl_categories`, to also work with `tbl_categories_custom`.
I think I must UNION these tables first somehow, but I don't understand how.

Comment: _Small Point_ DDL commands have an implied COMMIT as part of their function, so you dont need `COMMIT;`

Comment: What is your version of MySQL?

Comment: @trincot Development environment: 10.3.25-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, production environment: 10.4.17-MariaDB-log-cll-lve

Comment: So the parent category of a record in the new table will never refer to another record in the new table. Did I get that right?

Comment: It can. "tbl_categories" starts at categoryId 1 and will not go past 999. "tbl_categories_custom" starts at categoryId 1000. Both tables are identical in structure. categories in "tbl_categories_custom" CAN have their categoryParentId set to a categoryId in "tbl_categories". But also to a categoryId in the same "tbl_categories_custom" table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your version of MySQL (MariaDB 10.3) supports common table expressions, so you have a way to avoid the use of mutating variables in your queries. Mutating variables in a query has been a way to [perform hierarchical queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33737203/5459839) before common table expressions were supported, but it is a tactic that is deprecated and for which there is no documented guarantee that it will always work as intended.

So here is the query to do the same with a common table expression (cte), where 8 is the example value (replace it with the PHP expression):

```
with recursive 
cte as (
    select 1 as categoryDepth,
           c.* 
    from   tbl_categories c
    where  categoryId = 8
    union
    select cte.categoryDepth + 1, 
           c.*
    from   cte
    inner join tbl_categories c
            on c.categoryId = cte.categoryParentId
)
select   * 
from     cte
order by categoryDepth desc;
```

And now, when you have this second table, you can first do a common table expression for defining the union, and then continue as above:

```
with recursive 
base as (
    select * from tbl_categories
    union
    select * from tbl_categories_custom
),
cte as (
    select 1 as categoryDepth,
           base.* 
    from   base
    where  categoryId = 8
    union
    select cte.categoryDepth + 1, 
           base.*
    from   cte
    inner join base
            on base.categoryId = cte.categoryParentId
)
select   *
from     cte
order by categoryDepth desc;
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Thanks. I like your use of the CTE. I was on a similar path for a function that does the opposite. Perhaps you could look at that one as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65687860/cleaner-sql-cte-than-the-current-one